# Postgreql json data how to list all elements of an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonB field in postgresql DB table, it has data like this

```
{
  "units": [
    {
      "id": 299872379221376,
      "unitNumber": "1",
      "unitFloorSpace": 1,
      "createdTimeStamp": 1587994498586
    },
    {
      "id": 299872417011074,
      "unitNumber": "2",
      "unitFloorSpace": 2,
      "createdTimeStamp": 1588001330085
    }
  ]
}
```

I just want to list all unitNumbers like below, what would be the query for that?

1,
2,

I have tried below json query but that doesn’t list

```
Select form_data -> units -> unitNumbers from table where row_id =1;
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_extract_path(jdata,'units')) ->> 'unitNumber' as UnitNumber
from tableName;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d1b9b7fd1f2e527eae13951110c148fb)*